# Regular expression on digits if there no letters before

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will get digits only if theres no letters infront.

```
DoThis(0.5) // = 0.5 should be selected
DoThis5(43) // = 43 should be selected, but not 5
```

I managed to write this `/[0-9.]+\b/g` but it will select the '5' from `DoThis5()`. Which is what I dont want.

Comment: btw, all (current) answers here will match `............` - which isn't a number last time I checked. ;) If this matters, use something like `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead of the `[\d.]+` or `[0-9.]+` parts.

Comment: @Peter - It dose matter. I want the '.' only if its before a digit. I came up with this `(\b[0-9]+)|([.])+(\d+)` but im not good with regex. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `\b` operator available, why don't you do `\b[0-9.]+` (the plus is greedy, so will eat all the digits it finds).

**Edit:** With a stricter regex for decimal numbers with zero or one dot and at least one number;

```
\b[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

This currently disallows 10. and .5.  It requires a regex engine which supports parentheses for grouping, and question mark for an optional part.  (Some old versions of `sed` and e.g. Emacs require you to backslash the parentheses and the question mark.)

Comment: you can use `+?` to make regex ungreedy

Comment: That's hardly useful, here.  I am attempting to explain why you don't need a `\b` at the end.

Comment: @Fabio, why would you want to match reluctantly (ungreedy)?

Comment: This works great, except now i need it to also say 'Only . if infront (or in between) of digit'. Whichever makes more sense. In random places the '.' is selected. But i'd like it only selected in between digits.

Comment: I just added a comment to the answer which will only match `.` when between digits. It doesn't match `.5` though, so needs updating if that's needed too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookbehind ig the regex engine you're using supports it:

```
(?<!\w)[0-9.]+\b
```

Comment: you must escape the dot otherwise all char is valid

Comment: Not correct.  Inside a character class, dot only matches itself.

Comment: It doesn't look likes its supported for me. But that would really come in handy. Which engines do support the 'look behind'?

Comment: Generally, Perl-compatible regular expressions (the kind which supports (?:nongrouping) and backslash escapes like \d for digit, \w for word, etc.  The backslashes were already in Perl 4, whereas the ? stuff was introduced in Perl 5.

Comment: Most of them support (at least) fixed width lookbehind. JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: Your idea of "most of them" doesn't include awk, sed, grep, egrep, or a bunch of other "classical" regex implementations.

Comment: That's true. :) I tried to edit my comment to clarify I was referring to programming languages, but apparently I'm not allowed to edit it. :/

Comment: Perl5 was released **almost two decades ago.**  That's a really long time. Anything that claims Perl5 is too new to bother with probably thinks any human being  in high school today and likely college and even grad school too is also too new to bother with. There is no reason today ever to use languages with primitive regexes only, and every reason to use modern ones with full Unicode support per UTS#18, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
/\([0-9.]+\)/
```

this will match numbers that are enclosed between `()`

Answer (score 0):

If you cn't use negative look behind, this will work:

```
/\([0-9.]+\)/


echo "DoThis5(43)" | egrep -o "\([0-9.]+\)"                                                                                
(43)
```

Comment: This still grabs any number, even if it is adjacent to an alphabetic.

Comment: @tripleee, no, it matches digits surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: but this doesn't match decimal numbers

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was thinking those were grouping parentheses, but obviously, that's not what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/[^\w]([\d\.]+)/
```

explain:

`[^\w]`  every character that isn't a word character (like `[^a-zA-Z]`)

`[\d\.]` every digit (like `[0-9]`) and the dot char (escaped)

Comment: This will fail if the number is at beginning of line, although in this case, perhaps that is a non-issue.

Comment: This should allow a number at the beginning of input to also match: `(?:^|[^\w])([\d.]+)` ?  _(note the . not escaped inside the char class!)_